# Really annoying problem with emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

Many times I cannot get my application to install on the emulator.

I receive the following error from Eclipse:

> [2010-08-06 09:33:48 - Emulator]
>   2010-08-06 09:33:48.868
>   emulator[392:903] Can't open input
>   server
>   /Library/InputManagers/MultiClutchInputManager.bundle

The emulator boots, but the application is not installed.

MultiClutch is a 3rd party preference pane for OS X that allows you to capture gestures and specify what they should do.  I've uninstalled MultiClutch (using AppCleaner), yet I still receive this error.  I'm not quite sure what makes Eclipse decide to ignore it, but after attempting to run enough times, a NEW (read: second) emulator window will open and the application will install.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Andrew are u using NDK? what versión¡?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the library component of the Android is not proper.

solution : what you can do is update the Android SDK. and create new AVD and install latest ADT plugin it will be resolved